# Lunar orbit homework question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

[image: Homework question]

So what I did was find the potential energy of the lander at the 50km orbit and the 300km orbit, then I took the difference between the 2 potential energies and I though that would be the work done by the thrusters, as there are no other forces except gravity, but that doesn't seem right for some reason and it gave me wrong result as well.

How should this question be approached? And why can't I just take the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: The kinetic energy of the lander will also be different in a different orbit.

Comment: You should really, by the rules of this site, show your own workings out, you know?